# How to Shim DbContext with Microsoft Fakes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, mocking

I am creating a unit test that invokes a create task method. The create task method calls some mocked external object which are the purpose of my test, but inside my tested method there is also a `SaveChanges` call that saves my task.
What I am trying to do is to shim the `DbContext` class inside `System.Data.Entity` so that the `SaveChanges` method no longer accesses the database.

I have added a fake assembly for `System.Data.Entity` but when I use `System.Data.Entity`.Fakes it says "cannot resolve symbol 'Fakes'", though I can access `System.Data.Fakes` (but I have't added a fake assembly for System.Data)

I have faked other methods in my entities context, but I can't fake SaveChanges method on my entity since the method is inherited from DbContext.

```
ShimDBEntities.AllInstances.SaveChanges = (x) => { ... };
```

the upper chunk of code says "cannot resolve symbol 'SaveChanges'".

So how can I shim DbContext using Microsoft Fakes?

Comment: I'm not such a fan of Shims, especially on your DbContext. I think you might need to reconsider your design to better unit test your code. Check my blog post on this subject: http://sitecore.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/the-repo-man

Comment: thank, but the project is already in production and the design hasn't been thought to be testable so I was trying to work with what I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do it by creating a `SaveChanges` method in my `BaseRepository` class and use it in all of my derived repositories where I had `db.SaveChanges`.

Then I shimed my `BaseRepository` so that my `SaveChanges` method would do nothing